# Code in if else statement with boolean condition

Tags: java, boolean

I have written this below code. Since I am assigning the boolean value as false so and then again assigning false to `b` variable in `if` statement so the condition is true and output should be "hello". However, the output coming is "hi". Can anyone please enlighten me?

```
boolean b= false;

if (b=false){
    System.out.println("hello");        
}
else {  
    System.out.println("hi");
}
```

Comment: In `if (b=false)`, `=` is the assignment operator

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, try reading the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section before posting anything.

Answer (score 1):

try `(b == false)` or `(!b)`

you are checking against the assignment operator when you do `b=false`, you want to use `==` to check equality

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with your

```
b=false
```

`=` is an assignment operator. What you need is `==` which will compare.

If want to check whether a boolean is false you can also use `!b` which is equivalent to `b== false`.

Answer (score -2):

When the following line is executed:

```
if(b=false)
```

false is assigned to b and then b's value is used to evaluate the if condition which would become

```
if(false)
```

thus the control of the program will go to the else block.

You can do something like this:

```
if( !(b=false) ) { 
    System.out.println("hello"); 
} 
else { 
    System.out.println("hi"); 
}
```